# Duplicate post/product permalinks. (Link is temporary)

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, duplicates

We have 8 different types of products on our site. Often I will duplicate a similar product when creating a new similar product.

So instead I created 8 drafts that contain most of info I need when creating a new product within those 8 product types.

I copied the `duplicate` links of each of those product drafts and inserted their links into my admin bar so i can quickly add new products based on those 8 drafts.

For example of a duplicate link:

```
wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=product&action=duplicate_product&post=178395&_wpnonce=fb5a61e153
```

But i noticed this only works for a while and the `wpnonce=fb5a61e153` at the end of the link changes with time.. Rendering the duplicate link useless.

---

So right now I am just inserting the copied `duplicate` draft links into my admin bar as quick links. But since its based on some type of session.. and the link expires.. How do i insert a link that doesn't expire?

*(Sorry for the rough explanation trying to grasp what to do)*

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You should have it create a valid `wpnonce` on the fly.

Have a look at

- [wp_nonce_url()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nonce_url)
- [wp_create_nonce()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_create_nonce)

Are you using a plugin to duplicate your products? If so, you may need to dig through the plugin and specify the same `action` when you create your `wpnonce`.